# How can I set Searchview with Databinding

Tags: android

I can do filtering with searchview with normal coding. But I am currently using the Databinding method by changing my code. In this method, I cannot do databinding operations in searchview.

My activity.xml layout. I added data tags to my XML file, but I couldn't filter as I wanted

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorMainLayout"
    android:padding="@dimen/background_margin"
    tools:context="com.ismailhakkiaydin.doctorsapi.activity.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/search_view"
            android:elevation="1dp"
            android:queryHint="Klinik ara.."
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
            android:background="@drawable/linear_layout"
            android:elevation="1dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView">


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbKadin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_cb_left"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_cb_top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_cb_bottom"
                android:onClick="cbOnClick"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorCheckBox"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand"
                android:text="Kadın"
                android:textColor="@color/colorCheckBoxText" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbErkek"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_two_cb"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_cb_top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_cb_bottom"
                android:onClick="cbOnClick"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorCheckBox"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand"
                android:text="Erkek"
                android:textColor="@color/colorCheckBoxText" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/recyclerview_layout"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
            tools:listitem="@layout/list_item" />



    </LinearLayout>



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

My MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DoctorsViewModel mDoctorsViewModel;
private DoctorsAdapter mDoctorsAdapter;
private List<Doctors> mDoctorsList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActivityMainBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, 
R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = activityMainBinding.recyclerView;
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mDoctorsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DoctorsViewModel.class);
    mDoctorsAdapter = new DoctorsAdapter(this, mDoctorsList, new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Doctors doctors, int position) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserStateActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("doctors_info", doctors);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mDoctorsAdapter);


    mDoctorsViewModel.getAllDoctors().observe(this, new Observer<List<Doctors>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Doctors> doctors) {
            mDoctorsAdapter.setDoctorsList(doctors);
        }
    });



    activityMainBinding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            mDoctorsAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)){
                mDoctorsAdapter.getFilter().filter("");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


}
    }
```

My Adapter class. I did my filtering operations in my Adapter class. I wonder if I should use my adapter class this way in my Databinding management.

```
public class DoctorsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DoctorsAdapter.DoctorsViewHolder> implements 
Filterable {

private Context mContext;
private List<Doctors> doctorsList;
private List<Doctors> tempDoctorsList;
private ItemClickListener mItemClickListener;


public DoctorsAdapter(Context mContext, List<Doctors> doctorsList, ItemClickListener 
mItemClickListener) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.doctorsList = doctorsList;
    this.tempDoctorsList = doctorsList;
    this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}

@Override
public DoctorsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ListItemBinding mListItemBinding = 
DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    final DoctorsViewHolder doctorsViewHolder = new DoctorsViewHolder(mListItemBinding);

    mListItemBinding.getRoot().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(doctorsList.get(doctorsViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()), 
doctorsViewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });

    return doctorsViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DoctorsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Doctors doctors = doctorsList.get(position);
    holder.mListItemBinding.setDoctors(doctors);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (doctorsList != null) {
        return doctorsList.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public void setDoctorsList(List<Doctors> doctors) {
    this.doctorsList = doctors;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        FilterResults filterResults;

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {


            String searchString = charSequence.toString();
            if (searchString.isEmpty() || searchString.length() == 0) {
              //  IS_USER_NOT_FOUND_VISIBLE = false;
                tempDoctorsList = doctorsList;
            } else {
                List<Doctors> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Doctors doctor : doctorsList) {
                    if (doctor.getFullName().toLowerCase().contains(searchString)) {
                        filteredList.add(doctor);
                    }
                }
                tempDoctorsList = filteredList;
                if (tempDoctorsList.size() == 0) {
                  //  IS_USER_NOT_FOUND_VISIBLE = true;
                } else {
                  // IS_USER_NOT_FOUND_VISIBLE = false;
                }
            }
            filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = tempDoctorsList;
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults results) {
            tempDoctorsList = (List<Doctors>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    return filter;
}


class DoctorsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ListItemBinding mListItemBinding;

    public DoctorsViewHolder(@NonNull ListItemBinding mListItemBinding) {
        super(mListItemBinding.getRoot());
        this.mListItemBinding = mListItemBinding;
    }
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.


    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);


    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSystemService(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getComponentName()));
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


    newText = newText.toLowerCase();


    if(doctor.getFullName().contains(finalNewText)){

        //////

      }


    return true;
}
```

Comment: I know this method, I made such but it does not work. I am using databinding. How can I make with databinding?